# Locating Jython CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath, jython

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so please tell me if I am not adhering to the format guidelines or there is something I can do to improve the nature of my question.

I am trying to setup the Stanford-Parser in Python via Jython as suggested on the Stanford Parser page. Following the instructions on the github: 
https://github.com/vpekar/stanford-parser-in-jython
I was unable to locate the CLASSPATH for Jython.

Also, as a more general question is there a "better" way to setup the Stanford Parser in Python and/or the entire of Stanford CoreNLP?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "locating classpath"? Programatically determine what `python.home` property should be set to?

Comment: @doublep It isn't clear to me what it means when it says: Unpack into a local dir, put the path to stanford-parser.jar into the classpath for jython, namely where should I be putting the path

Comment: Sorry, I cannot really help then.  I would guess it should be on the same classpath as Jython itself, but not sure.

Comment: Thats precisely my question, how do I find the classpath for Jython itself